# How do I make an area unclickable with CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Let's say if I have wrapper div which includes some links and images, 
is there any way I can deactivate it at once with CSS only?

---

After review of answers:
I dropped the idea that can make it with CSS only.
jQuery blockUI plug in works like charm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you are going to use jQuery, you can easily accomplish this with the blockUI plugin. ...or to answer your question with CSS, you'll have to absolutely position the div over the content you wish to block. just make sure the absolutely positioned div comes after the content to be blocked for z-indexing purposes.

```
<div style="position:relative;width: 200px;height: 200px;background-color:green">
    <div>
        <a href="#">Content to be blocked.</a>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute;top:0;left:0;width: 200px;height:200px;background-color: blue;z-index:2;opacity:0.4;filter: alpha(opacity = 50)"></div>
</div>
```

sorry for all the inline css. you'll have to make some nice classes. Also, this has only been tested in firefox and IE7.

Answer (score 192):

There is a CSS rule for that:

`pointer-events: none;`

Check browser support: https://caniuse.com/pointer-events

Comment: The sole purpose of IE is to break internet usability

Comment: great, works in ff, safari and chrome, not in IE and opera. but who cares for them. +1 to @NullHead

Comment: It has been working in IE11 for a while, and I believe the same is true with Opera since it's blink-based now.

Comment: @NullHead, best way I've heard that put in years!

Comment: This has been working in FF since v31. IE 11 supports it but with a few issues. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: With `pointer-events: none`, you will not receive mouse move events, `:hover` ,`:active`....

Comment: What about going to the actual element with TAB and hitting ENTER ? How do you prevent that ?

Comment: This is now [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) by all modern browsers (IE11+).

Comment: I hope they put in the news that microsoft has ended support for IE, so that users will stop using it.

Answer (score 12):

These days you can just position a pseudo-element over the content.

```
.blocked
{
    position:relative;
}
.blocked:after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:1;
    background: transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HE5wR/27/

Comment: Because with `.blocked a:after` the pseudo-element you put over the div is part of the link itself, so it makes the whole div-area clickable, rather than blocking it.

Comment: That's now how it turns out. The whole `div` is not clickable, only the link, despite the CSS. See http://jsfiddle.net/HE5wR/26/. By the way, you had an error in your JavaScript with `isn't` which prematurely ended the string and gave a console error. I think you are saying the pseudo-element is also 'hot' and therefore acts as a link, despite being on top of the original link.

Comment: Yes, the pseudo-element will be hot, because it is part of the link-element. (And I fixed the jsfiddle, thanks.)

Comment: Excellent solution this. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I think this one works too:

**CSS**

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Answer (score 5):

Cover it up with another un-clickable element. You may need to use JavaScript to toggle this "cover" on and off. You can do something clever like make it semi-transparent or something as well.

```
<style>
    #cover {position:absolute;background-color:#000;opacity:0.4;}
</style>

<div id="clickable-stuff">
   ...
</div>
<div id="cover">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function coverUp() {
        var cover = document.getElementById('cover');
        var areaToCover = document.getElementById('clickable-stuff');
        cover.style.display = 'block';
        cover.style.width = //get areaToCover's width
        cover.style.height = //get areaToCover's height
        cover.style.left = //get areaToCover's absolute left position
        cover.style.top = //get areaToCover's absolute top position
    }

    /*
       Check out jQuery or another library which makes
       it quick and easy to get things like absolute position
       of an element
    */
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider to apply the event.preventDefault function of jQuery.
Here you can find an example:

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

TL;DR-version:

```
$("#element-to-block").click( function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

BAM!

Answer (score -3):

If you mean unclickable so that the users can't copy and paste it or save the data somehow. No this has never really been possible.

You can use the [jQuery BlockUI plugin](https://github.com/malsup/blockui/) or the CSS rule `pointer-events: none;` but that doesn't really prevent people from copying your text or images.

At worst I can always `wget` your content, and at best both css and js methods are easily circumvented using plugins like:

- "Allow right click" on [firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/re-enable-right-click/) or [chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-right-click/hompjdfbfmmmgflfjdlnkohcplmboaeo?hl=en)
- "Absolute enable right click and copy" on [firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/re-enable-right-click/) or [chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/absolute-enable-right-cli/jdocbkpgdakpekjlhemmfcncgdjeiika?hl=en)
- "Don't fuck with paste" on [firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/don-t-fuck-with-paste/) or [chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dont-fuck-with-paste/nkgllhigpcljnhoakjkgaieabnkmgdkb?hl=en)

Further to the point, unless you have a really good and legitimate excuse for breaking basic browser behavior, usability, accessibility, translation functionality, password managers, screenshot tools, container tools, or any number of various browser plugins functionality in the users right click context menu, please, just, stop, doing, this.