# how to make a area not clickable

Tags: jquery

I got a `<a>` that contains a `<input type="text">`
clicking the `<a>`will submit the parent form, the input in the `<a>` is for the quantity and as it is now trying to change amount it will trigger the form. i got idea of what how i could do this but i dont know how to finish the jquery, so i would appriciate some help

this is what i got so far

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.submit-parent-form').click(function() {              
            alert($(this).children('#quantity').val());
        });

        $('.input-a-tag').focus(function(){
            $(this).parent('.submit-parent-form') //here i need to prevent the click
        });
    });
```

html

```
<a class="submit-parent-form"><input id="quantity" type="text" class="input-a-tag" value="1" /></a>
```

**EDIT**
I see not that my solution wont work how i thought based on that the `<a>` gets the click before the focus, any ideas on how i could do
**EDIT 2**
the problem is when i try to get to the input in the a tag, trying to change the quantity

Comment: Try to take a look at this answer: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775215/how-do-i-make-an-area-unclickable-with-css

Comment: thanks for link but does not really help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
$('.input-a-tag').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

this should make click on the input element, not propagating to it's parent.

Answer (score 1):

```
var prevent = false;
$(".submit-parent-form").click(function(e){         

    if(prevent)
        e.preventDefault();
    else
        alert($(this).children('#quantity').val());
});

$(".submit-parent-form").focus(function(){
    prevent = true;
});


$(".submit-parent-form").blur(function(){
    prevent = false;
});
```

See how it works at http://jsfiddle.net/zND4B/4/

EDIT:
I added alert that shows before activating href in a on http://jsfiddle.net/zND4B/6/
Note that a can be without href.

Comment: yes, oneliner is exactly this in one line (+1 for it), but it did not occurred to me :)

Answer (score -1):

Simple way is:

```
$("#ElementName").css("pointer-events","none");
```