# Block a <div> to avoid interacting with the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs, one inside the other, and i want block the inside div (div2) for guest users, so they can't interactuate with that div, I want they only can see the image that generates the javascript.

This is the code:

```
<DIV id="div1" style="overflow:hidden; position:fixed; top:80px; left:0px; height:52; width:177; "  onClick="location.href='login.php'">

<div id="div2">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/chat/livehelp_js.php?eo=1&relative=Y&amp;department=1&amp;serversession=0&amp;pingtimes=60&amp;filter=Y&amp;"></script>
</div>

</DIV>
```

I tried with z-index and it don't works

What can i do for lock the div2? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? something like "disabled"?

Comment: You can do that by maintaining sessions in php.. if you mean something like to disable the inner div.

Comment: Do you want its visibility hidden or completely in accessible to the guest users

Comment: DO you want to stop guest user from interacting with div2?

Comment: try it:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775215/how-do-i-make-an-area-unclickable-with-css

Comment: I don't want to hide div2, just i want block the content, something like "disabled". Thanks for replies

Comment: doesn't work @Nishant thanks for the replie.

Comment: @Minucioso - what level of support do you want for IE browsers? IE7+, IE8+ etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make another transparent div over the one, you need to block.

Try this: [Create a Modal Dialog](http://raventools.com/blog/create-a-modal-dialog-using-css-and-javascript/)

Just make overlay div visible, if not logged in, and hidden, if logged in.

Comment: @Minucioso - you will have to use a transparent PNG as a background to make it work in IE. Or you can add a very slight `background-color` to the div. If a div has no `background-color`, `background-image` or content then it is "empty" and IE treats it as if it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that if you 'block' div2 using css (or embedded style tags) they can be easily undone. A couple of clicks in FireBug and the div would be 'unblocked'. Also 'manually' issuing a request against the url would bypass any 'blocking'.

Would it not be better for the service at /chat/livehelp... or similar to return and empty div when the user is not logged in?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i could help you, but with plugins like jQuery-UI (or maybe Kendo-UI?) u can easily manage dialog forms

es. [Dialog demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-disabled)

otherwise i think u have to hack with some js + css + html tricks...