# kendo UI drag event on WP8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, kendo-ui

I am not able to override KendoUI dataviz drag events on my WP8. Resulting is not able to scroll page when dragged from chart itself.

So far I have tried using in,

1)

```
 $("#<%= id %>").kendoChart({ 
            dragStart: function(e) {e.preventDefault();},
            drag: function(e) {e.preventDefault();},
            dragEnd: function(e) {e.preventDefault();},
            zoomStart: function(e) {e.preventDefault();},
            zoom: function(e) {e.preventDefault();},
            zoomEnd: function(e) {e.preventDefault();},
            seriesClick: function(e) {e.preventDefault();},
            seriesHover: function(e) {e.preventDefault();}
...
});
```

Which works on other touch devices like iphone,ipad but not on WP8.

2) Then I tried using jquery override events on parent DIV. parent.click(). parent.hover() and also unbind() all events, did not help.

3) Overlay div tag using [How do i make an area unclickable with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775215/how-do-i-make-an-area-unclickable-with-css). Seems like z-index is something not working on IE10.

4) Tried using e.stopPropagation along with e.preventDefault and that did not help either.

5) Also tried one more solution from another answer,

```
svg {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

i'm frustrated with IE10 on WP8. Can any one suggest an other workaround for this issue? I will owe you one.