# How to "force" a krajee bootstrap daterangepicker to be readonly?

Tags: yii2, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using [krajee DatePicker](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datepicker).

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;
use yii\web\View;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use kartik\widgets\DatePicker; 
use yii\web\JsExpression;

echo DatePicker::widget([
    'name' => 'dp',
    'id' => 'dp',
    'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_INLINE,
    'value' => '',
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'startDate' => $model->fecha_inicio,
        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        'beforeShowDay' => new \yii\web\JsExpression("function(date) {
            startDate = new Date('".$model->fecha_inicio."');
            endDate = new Date('".$model->fecha_fin."');
            between=startDate<=date && endDate>=date;
            console.log(date+' '+ (between)); 
            dateFormat = date.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + ('0'+(date.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0'+date.getUTCDate()).slice(-2);
            if (dateFormat == '".$model->fecha_inicio."') {
              return {classes: 'start-date', tooltip: 'Title'};
            }
            if (dateFormat == '".$model->fecha_fin."') {
              return {classes: 'end-date', tooltip: 'Title'};
            }
            if (between) {
              return {classes: 'in-range available'}; //create a custom class in css with back color you want
            }
            return false;
        }"),
    ],
    'options' => [
        // you can hide the input by setting the following
         'class' => 'hide'
    ]
]);
```

Is there any way to render the DateRangePicker without it being able to recieve user input? (eg. no hover, no date selection). I want to render it on a webpage just to inform the user of a range, but the fact that the user can interact with it feels awkward in this scenario.

Comment: You give a  link to `DateRangePicker` , but in your code you are using `DatePicker`. Can you please clear, which class are you using? Maybe just show your `use` section

Comment: My bad, I considered using daterangepicker, but ended up using datepicker.... I will edit my question ASAP

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add "readonly" to the options. Just like this:

```
'options' => [
    // you can hide the input by setting the following
     'class' => 'hide',
     'readonly' => 'readonly'
]
```

Comment: The "readonly" property, only makes the html text input readonly, the user is still able to interact with the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in your options array attribute `disabled`. SO it would be

```
  'options' => [
       'disabled' => 'true',
         'class' => 'hide'
   ]
```

Comment: This only makes the html input disabled, the user can still hover and select dates :/

Answer (score 0):

Well, this helped me do the trick, based [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10350911/1704242).

Basically, I ended up using a wrapping div with the style:

```
<div style="pointer-events:none;"> ... </div>
```

This solved it easily and directly, and [it seems to have decent cross-browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).

```
<?php
echo '<div class="well well-sm" style="background-color: #fff; width:245px; pointer-events:none;">';
$date = new \DateTime($model->fecha_inicio);
$days = Proceso::calcularDias ($model->fecha_inicio,$model->fecha_fin);

echo DatePicker::widget([
    'name' => 'dp',
    'id' => 'dp',
    'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_INLINE,
    'value' => '',
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'defaultViewDate' =>    ([
            'year'=>(int)$date->format('Y'),
            'month'=>$date->format('m')-1,
            'day'=>(int)$date->format('d')
        ]),
        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        'beforeShowDay' => new JsExpression("function(date) {
            startDate = new Date('".$model->fecha_inicio."');
            endDate = new Date('".$model->fecha_fin."');
            between=startDate<=date && endDate>=date;
            dateFormat = date.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + ('0'+(date.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0'+date.getUTCDate()).slice(-2);
            if (dateFormat == '".$model->fecha_inicio."') {
              return {classes: 'start-date', tooltip: 'Title'};
            }
            if (dateFormat == '".$model->fecha_fin."') {
              return {classes: 'end-date', tooltip: 'Title'};
            }
            if (between) {
              return {classes: 'in-range available'}; //create a custom class in css with back color you want
            }
            return false;
        }"),
    ],
    'pluginEvents'=>[
    ],
    'options' => [
       'disabled' => 'true',
        // you can hide the input by setting the following
         'class' => 'hide'
    ]
]);
echo '</div>';
?>
```